# Refresh squid cache on calendar

Tags: squid

Is it possible in squid to refresh parts of the cache on a set date of the month say?

I have data that gets regenerated once a month on a specific day, which I'd then like squid to cache for the next month, before marking it as stale.

A refresh pattern of refresh_pattern /path 0 100 60*24*30 won't work, because you can't guarantee that it will sync up with data refreshes.

Comment: There's a whole set of HTTP headers that allow you to specify exactly when a resource is to be considered stale.  Why aren't you using those instead?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think is a simple, practical approach to dealing with this:

You can (pre-)populate the squid cache by using `wget --cache=off -r` to spider the entire website(s) you want cached.

As far as scheduling it is concerned, can't you use the completion of the regeneration process to kickoff a prepopulation run?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you can't *refresh* an item in the cache using squid on it's own, but [you can *purge* an item](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/OperatingSquid#How_can_I_purge_an_object_from_my_cache.3F), then use wget or similar to populate the revised version. But the right way to solve the problem is, either as womble suggests, to set the right caching information on the origin server or to use different URLs for each version.